# if document by ID has a style=none then XXX else XXXX

Tags: javascript

Can somebody please... here is the code I'm trying to twick out..

```
if(document.getElementById('nameA').style.display == "inline") {
document.getElementById('nameB').style.display == 'block';
}
```

So I guess you understood what I'm trying to do, IF  has a style="display: inline;" then apply to  style="display: block"...

Can somebody please help me with this... it appears that this doesn't want to work... is it possible to ask with javascript and check if a  has "style=inline"?

Thank you

P.S. Thanks to everyone who minused, hope you will get the same "help" when you will have questions and/or problems.

Comment: `document.getElementById('nameB').style.display = 'block';` will do the trick

Comment: == test = assignment. Also you need to set the style on the tag to read it before you test

Comment: @user2145511: Why did you change your question to use `==` inside the `if` block? It was originally correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the initial style is set in CSS or by the element's default, then it won't show up on the `style.display`.

If that's the case, just check to see if the `style.display` has been assigned a value at all, and if not, make it `block`.

```
if (document.getElementById('nameA').style.display == "") {
    document.getElementById('nameB').style.display = 'block';
}
```

---

Or if it's possible that it will have been given a manual `"inline"` then you may need to check for both.

```
var disp = document.getElementById('nameA').style.display;

if (disp == "" || disp == "inline") {
    document.getElementById('nameB').style.display = 'block';
}
```

---

Also, be certain you are fetching by the ID value, and not the NAME. The `nameA` makes me think that you may be trying to target the wrong attribute.

Also make sure that the elements have been loaded before selecting them. And as always, keep your developer's console  open and check for errors.